# Add line break to HTML from Js loop

Tags: javascript, html, web

I have a simple Js function that generates a list of random numbers based on how many the user wants. The function works fine, and logs fine, but it isn't displaying like I'd like it to. I'm new to Javascript, so I tried using the `\n` escape character, but it didn't do anything. Any help would be appreciated.

```
function generateIDs() 
{

var num = document.getElementById('numberToGenerate').value;
var par = document.getElementById('numbers');
var button = document.getElementById('genButton');
button.disabled = true;

for (var x=0;x<num;x++) 
{

var id = Math.floor((Math.random()*10000)+1);
par.innerHTML = id;


}


    <form>
Auto-Generate <input type="text" name="number" id="numberToGenerate"/> IDs.
<button type="button" onclick="generateIDs()" id="genButton">Go!</button>
</form>

<p id="numbers">

</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

`\n` doesn't mean much to a browser; use `<br/>` instead.

Example:

```
// snip
for (var x=0;x<num;x++) 
{
    var id = Math.floor((Math.random()*10000)+1);
    par.innerHTML = id.toString() + '<br/>';       
}
//snip
```

Note that this is going to overwrite the previous value on each iteration. You probably want this:

`par.innerHTML += id.toString() + '<br/>';`

Comment: how would you reset this, to prevent printing again without clearing the field.